# How do I analyze JavaScript code written in .php file in SonarQube

Tags: javascript, php, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using SonarQube for code analysis. SonarQube is enabled to analyze all languages (we have removed parameter `sonar.language=`).
We have `.php` file; file has PHP and also has JavaScript code written it.
We know that JavaScript code is having some error but the SonarQube analysis is not detecting that error.

How do I perform SonarQube analysis so that we can rectify our JavaScript code if there are any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not supported, there is a ticket for [feature here](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/581). You can follow and vote for it.
In the meanwhile, if you have some bigger chunks of JavaScript in your PHP files, you can consider extracting them into standalone `.js` files, which will be analyzed as usual.